# Launch MapMouseEvent in FLEX via alt + mouse click

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

I would like to launch a MapMouseEvent via a combination of keyboard short cuts and a mouse click.  This is a portion of what I have, and I am not sure if the logic is correct:

```
private function MapClick(event:MapMouseEvent):void 
  {
    if (event.altKey) altPressed = true;
        {
           Alert.show("Alt key has been pressed - click on screen");
           // launch the function here
        }
    else
        {
           Alert.show(" Must click Alt key first, then click on map");
        }
  }
```

I have looked at similar examples on this site but still have not reach any solution.  I am hoping that someone who knows FLEX can help me to basically launch a function via a series of Keyboard shortcut.  For example: Alt + mouse click, or Shift + mouseclick, or something along those lines. The reason is that a simple mouse click already does something else on the screen.

Thanks ...

RJ

Answer (score 0):

The code you've provided is very close to correct.

```
private function MapClick(event:MapMouseEvent):void 
  {
    if (event.altKey);
        {
           //This means alt is held, AND a click occurred.
           //run function for alt-click here
        }

    if (event.ctrlKey);
        {
           //This means ctrl is held, alt was *not* held, AND a click occurred.
           //run function for ctrl-click here
        }

    if (!event.ctrlKey && !event.altKey)
        {
           //this means that a click occurred, without the user holding alt or ctrl
           //run function for normal click here.
        }
  }
```

The way I wrote this, if a user holds ctrl+alt and clicks, BOTH functions run. If you'd rather have alt have priority over ctrl, or similar, the below code will work.

```
private function MapClick(event:MapMouseEvent):void 
  {
    if (event.altKey);
        {
           //This means alt is held, AND a click occurred.
           //run function for alt-click here
        }
    else if (event.ctrlKey);
        {
           //This means ctrl is held, AND a click occurred.
           //run function for ctrl-click here
        }
    else
        {
           //this means that a click occurred, without the user holding alt or ctrl
           //run function for normal click here.
        }
  }
```

Comment: Hey Sam:   Thanks for the reply.  I have been off line a bit (late reply) so sorry about that.  Yeah I should of know better to exclude the else statements here.   Ok  will check it out to see if I can get it going ...